# how do I hide embed path using php?

Tags: php, image, path

I do have an api or and access path like this

http://www.example.com/data/key/25645896/view.jpg

I want hide this actual path from my webpage.

Comment: What are you doing with this path? What do you mean by "hide" exactly? This makes no sense yet

Comment: this is just an example. actually the original link is embed in a web page and displaying an image.

Comment: @aron so you want the browse to load an image but you don't want to reveal the  URL?

Comment: If an api provides you with a resource then the resource url shouldn't contain your key. Are you sure this is the case?

Comment: This reminds me of a child closing their eyes so no one can see them

Comment: actually I want hide image path(it is not image but an swf file)

Comment: yes this resource url contain the key and it is open

Comment: So what does the api documentation suggest? There's only two possibilities. 1) It doesn't matter if the public sees the key 2) Your not supposed to publicly link the resource

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a small PHP "proxy", which will retrieve the image using secret key and then send it to client without it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting the URL to point to a PHP script under the covers, say for instance to change your URL to http://www.example.com/data/key/view.php?id=25645896, you could use Apache mod_rewrite to do this.

Comment: You can find the Apache mod_rewrite documentation here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html   You'd want a rule something like `RewriteRule ^data\/key\/(\d+)\/view.jpg /data/key/view.php?id=$1`